# Login link not working in navigation bar HTML

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

so I am using django and while all the links in my navbar work perfectly fine when I click them, the `login` link does not work in the navbar. I am clicking the link but the page doe not reload. But when I am right-clicking my mouse and selecting `Open link in new tab` then I am taken to the login page. Same with `logout` link when I am logged in.

Anyone has any ideas why this is happening and can anyone please help me fix this?
Thanks in advance!

My code:

```
  <header class="main-header clearfix" role="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="{% url 'index' %}"></em>Class</a>
    </div>
    <a href="#menu" class="menu-link"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    <nav id="menu" class="main-nav" role="navigation">
      <ul class="main-menu">
        <li><a href="#section1">Home</a></li>
        <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#section2">About Us</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#section2">Who we are?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section3">What we do?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section3">How it works?</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#section4">Courses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section5">Video</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section6">Contact</a></li>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
        {% else %}
          <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

My urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"), 
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
]
```

Comment: Can you share your urls? Have you tried putting some other link inside `<a href>`? (Like google.com)

Comment: @NixonSparrow same thing happens even if I put `google.com` in `<a href />`. 
I have included my urls.py

Comment: It works when I am changing the navbar html

Comment: Seems ok, but you have weird `</em>` :) Can you share your css? Maybe there you have some left-click blockers.

Comment: My css was taken from a free template so it's huge